# Extract values delimited by characters without characters with regex (LabView)

Tags: regex, labview

I want to extract the number sandwiched between two specific letters.

e.g. string: x23y4z90

I specify x and y , I get 23
I specify y and z , I get 4
I specify z and x , I get 90 (the string pattern loops)

`x\dy` yields `x23y`, but I don't want the letters included.

*note: This is to read sensor values serially in LabVIEW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use groups:

```
x(\d+)y
```

Now, the second group will contain only the number. The first group will be the whole match.

Another possibility is to use positive lookahead and positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=x)\d+(?=y)
```

Please note the `+` I added. This is necessary to match numbers with multiple digits.

Check it [here for x and y](http://regexr.com?33qp8) and [here for y and z](http://regexr.com?33qp5).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lookarounds or groups

```
(?<=x)\d+(?=y)
-----    ----
 |         |->only checks if y is after a digit(lookahead) 
 |->only checks if x is before a digit(lookbehind)
```

Comment: Perfect. I can only accept one answer, and Daniel had the nice links. But thanks so much for the quick and correct reply.